# How to dynamically set text on a label inside an EditForm template?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I've got a DevExpress 11 ASPxGridView in a .NET 3.5 ASP.NET web forms application. I'm trying to get a header in the edit form, and am doing that like this currently:

```xml
<Templates>
  <EditForm>
    <h3>Edit item details</h3>
    <dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement runat="server" ID="tr" ReplacementType="EditFormContent"/>
  </EditForm>
</Templates>
```

This is working fine. However, I want to localize the text in the `<h3>Edit item details</hr>`, but can't seem to figure out a way to do so.

I've [Googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=DevExpress%20ASPxGridView%20localize%20EditForm%20content) around a bit but haven't found any solution. I've also tried changing it to an `asp:Label` with specific ID, and inside the `HtmlEditFormCreated` event I called:

```
gridViewEditFormEventArgs.EditForm.FindControl("myHeaderId")
```

However, this returns `null`.

I should note that I've got some custom localization going on, so basically I'm looking for a way to dynamically set some text inside the `EditForm` using code behind. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the

```
Label lbl = gridView.FindEditFormTemplateControl("myHeaderId") as Label;
```

method instead.